# Best practice for ordering social media login buttons?

Tags: design, login, social-media

Basically I have a login page, and it has log in with Facebook, Twitter, or Google.

What would be the best way to order them? I've often seen it be Facebook, Twitter, then Google, though I never understood why. Is there a good reason?

At other times it's mixed up. Why are they ordered like that? What significance does ordering them have? Which order would be best?

Comment: This is is a interesting question, I would also want to see if there are any studies on this matter. I feel frankly, it boils down to your target audience. Facebook, Google, Twitter have created their pockets of supporters. It was de facto standard to give Facebook, Twitter sometime back, but now there are allegiances with what these sites represent.You'd find a prominent log in using Google for Asana which is a productivity app. You'd see Quora putting Google ahead too. There would a game site somewhere putting Facebook first as it values the social aspect more. Probably depends on site focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering by popularity seems to be a good option.

Social login data for different quarters of 2014 from well-known social login providers such as Gigya, Janrain and LoginRadius show that the majority of users use Facebook and Google when compare with Twitter, hence if ordered by popularity, it would be Facebook, Google then Twitter. Of course, this information can vary based on the website nature and region.

- [Janrain - Social Login Trends Across the Web: Q4 2014](http://janrain.com/blog/social-login-trends-across-the-web-q4-2014/)
- [Gigya - The Landscape of Social Login: Facebook Sails, Yahoo
  Sinks](http://blog.gigya.com/the-landscape-of-social-login-facebook-sails-yahoo-sinks/)
- [LoginRadius - Social Login and Sharing Statistics for 2014 Q3](http://blog.loginradius.com/2014/10/social-login-sharing-statistics-2014-q3/)

Comment: I know of the statistics, but why would ordering them by popularity be good? How to order them and why, in terms of design?

Comment: @yaharga In terms of design, it really is a matter of personal preference since each website is ordering them in a different way. I only suggested the above as it seems like the only valid reason for ordering the social login options in a certain way.

Comment: Do the users log in to Google because of the order? Where did you read that ordering by popularity is a good option?

Comment: @yaharga It's just a suggestion. Please, do not take it too personal.

Comment: Why order by popularity? Because the user is most likely to be a member of the top one, next likely to be a member of the next, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Also another thing to keep in mind is that some companies want to attain the Profile data from its users. They use this data for marketing practices and understanding target audiences. Data points like Name, DOB, Location etc. Each Social platform delivers a variety of different profile data to the platform owner. The main one being Facebook.

Facebook profile data is a lot more extensive than other Social platforms. You can find a list of the available data points [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).

Twitter's profile data comes in a second with most of it focusing on activity within their platform other than their users. See their data points [here.](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users)

Google's API returns various profile data points and the can be found on their developers.google website.

Hope this helps.